# Moving an object according to the device camera movement (with sensors)

Tags: android, canvas, android-camera, android-sensors

for over a week I've been struggling with a feature to draw some picture on the screen (overlaying the camera preview), and then move the picture according to the motion of a camera. An example: I hold my phone in a landscape position (the app is always in that orientation) and look at my table with a camera. Afterwards I touch the screen to draw a box on that table, and then look at the ceiling with the phone camera - this should make the box go in an opposite direction - which is down (creating an illusion of the box really being there).

I am able to draw an obiect in a surface view with a transparent background, which overlays the camera preview and move the obiect up and down using the `Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY` (Z-axis readings). It works really smooth and perfectly mimics the up/down motion.

The problem starts, when I want to move it horizontally - I could not find a sensor type, which would help me achieve a desired effect.

To move the picture on the screen, I first save the current sensor reading when the user touched the screen (to paint a picture):

`temporaryX = ??` - (this I did not figure out yet). 
`temporaryY = accelerometerHandler.getAccelZ;`

Then subtract that value from the new reading:

`differenceX = newX - temporaryX;`
`differenceY = accelerometerHandler.getAccelZ - temporaryY;`

And then draw the picture on the canvas using those modificators:

`canvas.drawBitmap(image, posX + differenceX, posY + differenceY, null);`

I tried with `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`, which allowed me to move horizontally with quite good results, but the sensor readings also change when I look up or down, which messes with the vertical motion (the obiect moves at an angle).

Should I stick with sensors, or is there a different approach for the described problem? Even though I searched a for a similar question a lot - I could not find any topics which covered that problem. Thank you for all your answers!